# Working with PHP shell_exec and SpiderMonkey Javascript Shell

Tags: php, javascript, shell

Let say I have this code in a JS file called plus2.js:

```
function plus2(n){
    print (n+2);
};
plus2(n);
```

That's how it can be exacuted via PHP shell_exec:

```
echo shell_exec('js -f plus2.js');
```

Which doesn't return anythig because I have not informed a value to "n".

And that's the question: how can I pass a value to "n" via PHP shell_exec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arguments` list:

```
function plus2(n){
    print (n+2);
};
plus2(parseInt(arguments[0], 10));
```

Test:

```
[adrian@cheops3:~]> js test.js 1337
1339
```

To call it from your PHP code:

```
$result = system('js test.js 1337');
```